# Can't compile sample bpf program, bpf/bpf.h is missing

Tags: c, linux, bpf

I'm trying to compile the sample bpf program in Linux source code. So I downloaded the current kernel source code and entered `samples/bpf` folder

```
apt source linux
cd linux-*/samples/bpf
```

Then I tried to compile a sample program with gcc:

```
# gcc sock_example.c
sock_example.c:29:10: fatal error: bpf/bpf.h: No such file or directory
   29 | #include <bpf/bpf.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

And I'm unable to find `bpf/bpf.h` with `apt-file`

```
# apt-file find bpf/bpf.h
(no output)
```

What was wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Linux eBPF samples come with a rather long Makefile. It handles a lot of cases and integrates well with the kernel building workflow, but makes it more complicated to build the samples outside of the kernel tree.

For example, this Makefile adds a number of includes directories, such as [`TPROGS_CFLAGS += -I$(srctree)/tools/lib/`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/samples/bpf/Makefile#L201), meaning that `bpf/bpf.h` will not be fetched from your OS' libraries but from `tools/lib/` under your kernel repository.

Here are a few options that you can consider to compile your program:

- Adjust the existing Makefile to use it to build your own programs, for example by adding your kernel code to the `tprogs-y` target.
- Install libbpf from the kernel repo (`sudo make -C tools/lib/bpf install`) or from [its GitHub mirror](https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf/). This should install the headers, and gcc should then be able to find them.
- Adjust your compile option to tell gcc where to look for the header (`gcc -I <path/to/linux>/tools/lib`).
- (Adjust the include path in `#include <bpf/bpf.h>` to make it point to your library.)

Answer (score 5):

You need to install [libbpf](https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf):

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf
cd src
sudo make install
```